# Is there any other way to stop Media Player from playing on top of each other?

Tags: android, media-player

I got this code.

```
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tdesert);
    ImageButton ibtn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtn1);
    ibtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mp2.isPlaying()){
                mp2.pause();
                mp2.seekTo(0);
            }
            if (mp3.isPlaying()){
                mp3.pause();
                mp3.seekTo(0);
            }
            if (mp4.isPlaying()){
                mp4.pause();
                mp4.seekTo(0);
            }
            if (mp5.isPlaying()){
                mp5.pause();
                mp5.seekTo(0);

            }
            if (mp6.isPlaying()){
                mp6.pause();
                mp6.seekTo(0);

            }
            if (mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.pause();
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else{
                mp.start();
            }
            }

    });
```

But it's not so good to use it when you have lots of files
I got 64 files meaning 64 Media Players, now to type that code for all 64files, code would be too long.
Is there any other way to prevent Media Player plying on top of each other?
I am using ListView so writing that for all 64 Mp's code would be..just way to big. And I am afraid that could slow app or consume too much space on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa! Number of media files is **not** equal to number of `MediaPlayer` instances you should use! That would terribly hog system resources! Use a single `MediaPlayer` and use the methods `setDataSource()` then the `prepare()` method on that instance. When you're done playing a particular media, simply use the `reset()` or `stop()` method. After you call `reset()` or `stop()`, you'll have to re-initialize the same `MediaPlayer` instance.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram
for more details about the various methods that you should use.

Comment: I am new to android development, and I've been told to do so. Can you give me an example how it should look like?

Comment: That's wrong! One `MediaPlayer` is sufficient for a music app! For a tutorial, see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidMedia/article.html or http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/